# Why do I get a type mismatch during compile time

Tags: java, types, polymorphism, jung

I'm declaring a graph (using JUNG's Graph interface) as a class variable like this:

```
private Graph<Knoten, Kante> _graph;
```

I try to initialize it like this:

```
_graph = new DirectedSparseGraph<AttrKnoten, GewKante>();
```

AttrKnoten extends Knoten and GewKante extends Kante (they are just marker interfaces at the moment). I get the following error message during compile time:

```
"Type mismatch: cannot convert from DirectedSpareGraph<AttrKnoten, GewKante> to Graph<Knoten, Kante>"
```

Why is that? Is there any other way to handle this, but leaving out the parameters during declaration?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't do that with generics.

A simpler example:

```
List<CharSequence> list = new ArrayList<String>();
```

This doesn't work, even though `String` implements `CharSequence`.

---

The easiest solution is to just do:

```
_graph = new DirectedSparseGraph<Knoten, Kante>();
```

You can still add `AttrKnoten` and `GewKante` objects to `_graph`.

---

Alternatively, if you only want `AttrKonten` and `GewKante` objects, just declare it as:

```
private Graph<AttrKnoten, GewKante> _graph;
```